# Add attribute to IXMLDOMNode

Tags: vba, msxml, addattribute

I am getting `Run-time error 438: Object Doesnot support this propoerty or method` in the `xNamedNodeMap.setNamedItem (myNode)` line of the following code:

```
Sub appendChild()
    Dim xDoc As MSXML2.DOMDocument60
        Set xDoc = New MSXML2.DOMDocument60
        xDoc.LoadXML ("<root><child/></root>")
    Dim myNode As MSXML2.IXMLDOMNode
       Set myNode = xDoc.createNode(2, "Sci-Fi", "")
    Dim xNamedNodeMap As MSXML2.IXMLDOMNamedNodeMap
    Set xNamedNodeMap = xDoc.DocumentElement.ChildNodes.Item(0).Attributes
    xNamedNodeMap.setNamedItem (myNode)
    Debug.Print xDoc.XML
End Sub
```

Can someone help me to debug the issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove the parentheses from `(myNode)`

```
xNamedNodeMap.setNamedItem myNode
```

You should not use parentheses when calling a method unless that method returns a value (and you wish to assign the return value to something).  Otherwise, the `()` cause VBA to *evaluate* the contained argument, and pass in the result of that evaluation instead of (eg) `myNode`

What happens when the argument you're passing is evaluated depends on what type of variable it is, and if it's an object whether that object has a `default method/property`.

Objects without a default method/property will raise a runtime error as you are seeing in your code.

**Note** - things are different when you're using `Call` but general advice here is don't use `Call`...

Comment: Thanks @TimWilliams. You were correct. The parenthesis were causing the issue.